# Can I write Jenkins custom steps for declarative pipelines in a way that gives me code completion?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I create custom steps like this: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-custom-steps

```
// vars/buildPlugin.groovy
def call(Map config) {
    node {
        git url: "https://github.com/jenkinsci/${config.name}-plugin.git"
        sh 'mvn install'
        mail to: '...', subject: "${config.name} plugin build", body: '...'
    }
}
```

Then it's called like this: `buildPlugin name: 'git'`

The problem is I don't get any code completion or type info for its parameters.

Is there a Groovy language feature Jenkins supports that would allow me to define the parameters a custom step needs similar to the properties of a class or arguments of a method? I was thinking about using an interface somehow, but doesn't look like Jenkins would support it: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-27927

I'm using declarative not scripted pipelines.

Comment: You could specify the parameters for the function explicitly instead of passing in an arbitrary `Map`. Even if this was a global variable method instead of a custom step function, you would still be limited with this usage.

Comment: perhaps my IDE is misconfigured, but autocomplete works for methods and properties of a class (inside a pipeline closure), but it doesn't for a "custom step" if I create it like this `def call(String param1, String param2, String param3){}` which is what I think your suggesting right?

Comment: I am not sure how the autocomplete would work in an IDE, but that pattern would indeed allow parameter definition for the custom step function, or similarly a global variable method.

Comment: Your suggestion is probably my best bet, I wonder though if there is a way to use a class/interface in a lightweight way here to write custom steps. I would mark your first suggestion as the answer as I see no better solution.

Comment: Lightweight? Probably not in my opinion. Since you linked to the relevant documentation, you have probably already seen https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#writing-libraries and the section below it. You could write a class, and then import it and reference its members in the custom step functions. That class should be able to be written in Groovy or Java. That may be closer to what you want?

Comment: I guess I could create a class/classes that generate config objects custom steps could take as input. seems like a lot of cruft though

Comment: Yeah I am not sure if what you are looking for truly exists at the moment.